# Is the comma category $y \downarrow X$ small?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category and $X \in \hat{\mathcal{C}}$ a presheaf. Is the comma category $y \downarrow X$ small?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: I guess $y$ is the Yoneda embedding. The Yoneda lemma implies $(y \downarrow X)$ is small.

Comment: @Shaun, Assuming AC: 

Set M to be the supremum of $|\hom_{\hat{\mathcal{C}}} (yc, X)|$ for $c \in \mathcal{C}$ (it exists, since each $\hom$ is a set and the class objects of $\mathcal{C}$ is a proper set). The class of objects of $y\downarrow X$ has at most $|\mathcal{C}_0| \cdot M$ elements, therefore $y\downarrow X$ is at least a locally small category. Let N be the supremum of $|\hom_{\hat{\mathcal{C}}} (yc, yc')|$ for $c, c' \in \mathcal{C}$, then $\hom(y\downarrow X)$ has at most $|\mathcal{C}_0| \cdot |\mathcal{C}_0| \cdot N$ elements and is as such a set.Thus $y \downarrow X$ is small

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh... okay.

Comment: @user139696 Is $y$ the Yoneda embedding or not? The question is simply unclear without you stating whether or not $y$ is the Yoneda embedding; if not, what is $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm detailing Zhen Lin's comment.

Yoneda's lemma states (notably) that for every object $c$ of $\mathcal C$, there is a bijection $\hom(y(c),X) \simeq X(c)$.

But the object of $(y\downarrow X)$ are precisely the arrows $y(c) \to X$ for all object $c$ of $C$. Then the class of objects of $(y\downarrow X)$ are in bijection with $\coprod_{c \in \operatorname{Ob}\mathcal C} X(c)$ : each $X(c)$ is a small set, and $\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal C$ is also a small set, so is the disjoint sum.

---

Following magma's suggestion, let's show that $(y \downarrow X)$ is locally small : the arrows in $(y\downarrow X)$ between the objects $y(c) \to X$ and $y(c') \to X$ are those arrow $f\colon c \to c'$ in $\mathcal C$ such that commutes
$$ \begin{matrix}
y(c) & \overset{y(f)} \longrightarrow & y(c') \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \searrow & & \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\swarrow  \\
& X. & 
\end{matrix} $$
So the $\hom(y(c) \to X,y(c')\to X) \subseteq \hom(c,c')$, and a subset of a small set is itself small.

Comment: nice! perhaps you could also add the proof that the homs in the comma category are small sets and thus show that the comma category is indeed small

Comment: @magma I edited. However, remark that there is nothing specific to the Yoneda embedding here : the "same" proof works to show that $(u\downarrow v)$ is locally small when the domain categories of $u$ and $v$ are locally small.

Comment: Pece: I know, you know but...does everybody know? Indeed the OP explicitly asked for that.